# A cron job forks/exec()s before terminating. What happens to the stdout of the child?

Tags: cron, exec

Normally, a cron job's `stdout` and `stderr` are e-mailed to me (as per the `MAILTO` setting in `crontab`) *when the job finishes*.

What if my job starts another job with `fork`/`exec` (or just plain `exec`) or with `system("foo &")`?

- What happens with the `stdout`/`stderr` of the child job? Will I get it via email?

An ideal outcome would be a separate email for the parent and the child, but I am pretty sure I would have to arrange that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child process inherits its stdin, stdout, and stderr from its parent. Fork and exec are common in cron jobs (consider that every command you run in a shell script involves a fork/exec). The output will generally go to the same cron email.

Having it go to a separate mail is easy enough: just pipe its stdout/stderr to `mail` (or similar):

```shell
#!/bin/sh

command-1 2>&1 | mail -s 'output 1' user@domain.com
command-2 2>&1 | mail -s 'output 2' user@domain.com
```

If you want cron's only email if not empty behavior, [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) includes a convenient `ifne` for that (`… | ifne mail -s…`).

Comment: DIUC that cron will not email me anything until the process and all its children terminate?

Comment: @sds I think what cron does is that the email won't be sent until everything has closed stdout/stderr (everything = the process cron started, and any children that inherited stdout/stderr from it). But I confess to having not tested that nor read the source code... But it could also just be the one process. Not sure.

Comment: @sds Actually, just read the source, and it appears cron waits for the child process, then mails. So if you spawn a command in the background, cron will send any email then stop caring about it. But if you exec something, that new thing continues with the same pid (so it is the child process), and cron won't email until that thing exits.